# Xnest from Mac OSX to HP-UX

Tags: mac-osx, hp-ux

I'm trying to connect to my HP-UX machine from Mac OS X using Xnest. The problem is that I can not get the keyboard to work. I can see the login-prompt, but unable to type in my username.

The connection is done by:

```
Xnest :1 -query 192.168.0.193 -geometry 1280x1024
```

and it gives me some errors:

```
(EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/X11/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (dlopen(/usr/X11/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so, 5): image not found)
(EE) GLX: could not load software renderer
(EE) XKB: Couldn't open rules file /usr/X11/share/X11/xkb/rules/base
(EE) XKB: No components provided for device Virtual core keyboard
Couldn't get keyboard.
```

I hope there is someone here who might have the answer :-).

Answer (score 0):

You should add -kb key. So it'd be

```
Xnest :1 -query 192.168.0.193 -kb -geometry 1280x1024
```

Good luck! ;)